# Hibernates fails to retrieve complete object from DB

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm facing the weird issue with Hibernate and got out of ideas why is this happening.

My Category entity is self-joined with One-To-Many relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")
private Category parentCategory;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentCategory", orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private Set<Category> childrenCategories;
```

I'm saving relationship between parent and child this way:

```
//passing preselected parentCategory and creating newCategory
newCategory.setParentCategory(parentCategory);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(newCategory);
```

This leads to two rows in DB:

```
ID|NAME |PARENT
1 |Test |(null)
2 |Test2|1
```

which seems Ok when #1 is parent and #2 is child.

I get data from DB with:

```
(Category) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Category.class, id);
```

When I do this with #1 - everything is OK, Hibernates gets complete object, with filled Set. However, when I'm trying to get #2, Hibernate actually maps only ID field:

```
Category@...
childrenCategories  null    
id  Integer  (id=111)   
name    null    
parentCategory  null    
products    null
```

which leads to multiple NPEs later in the code.

What could be the reason of such behavior? From my point of view, all relations are set correctly. Also I've tried to create similar class outside of my spring-context with similar approach and everything seems ok there.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Try to set `fetch` attribute to `EAGER` in `@ManyToOne` annotation, just like `@OneToMany`

Comment: Upon removing fetch = FetchType.EAGER from @OneToMany problem goes away. However, I'd want to know why is this happening at the first place.